# PHP: Conditional subpattern in regex?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I tried this in PHP:

```
<?php
 $greets1="hello jack"; $greets2="hi john";
 preg_match('/(hello)(?(1).*)/',$greets1,$result);
?>
```

I expected that the array `$result` contains `hello` and `jack`, but it only captures `hello`. Why?

Comment: You need to capture hi/hello and name? May be `/(hello|hi)\s+(\w+)/` will fit?

Comment: What is `(?(1).*)` supposed to do? Try `(.*)`

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I was trying to try conditional subpatterns,though.

Comment: @JoAreBy I was trying to do it with conditional subpatterns

Comment: @user176795 then you're using wrong syntax. Correct is `(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` but I don't see how it is relied with your sample.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo there's : `(?(1).*)` . If the 1st subpattern matches, capture `.*`, but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is correct, but it doesn't capture the second part of the match. Try:

```
/(hello)((?(1).*))/
```